# How to disable the google link in google maps sdk for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

From the Google documentation:

> The Google Maps SDK for iOS opens the Google Maps mobile app when the
>   user clicks the Google logo on the map

I have a requirement to disable this link. Is it possible with a non premium google account ? Or is it possible with the premium subscription ?

I just need to disable the link, not the logo itself. I know that on iOS 9 the link won't open if i don't add the scheme to the app's plist file. It would be nice to have this on ios 8 and 7 too.

Comment: Just add a clear color UIView with userInteractionEnabled set to YES on top of the GMSMapView. It will intercept all touches on the Google map.

Comment: That's exactly illegal act.

Comment: @Softlion Did you fix it, or something like official docs?

Comment: I switched to apple map.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Terms of Service says:

[10.5 Intellectual Property Restrictions.](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_5)

**g. No removing, obscuring, or altering terms of service, links, or proprietary rights notices.**

You will not:

1. **remove, obscure, or alter any Google terms of service or any links to or notices of those terms, or any copyright, trademark, or other proprietary rights notices**; or
2. falsify or delete any author attributions, legal notices, or other labels of the origin or source of material.

So you can not modify the Google's Logo except you have a contract with Google.

Comment: The question is not about the license, it is about the features of the SDK. I am asking if this is a feature (hidden somewhere in the doc) of the free or the paid sdk. It is not clear.

Comment: There is no feature to disable link in the SDK, and if you do with/without SDK, it is against the TOS. So I just warn the requirement itself is against the TOS. I recommend you should consider (or you should tell your client?) about this.

Comment: Well you don't answer the question, you just put threats. If you look at the question you'll see there is alreay the excerpt from the tos. My question is, is it possible with the premium subscription. And how. With links to arguments ;)

Comment: Nobody should look into this answer, it's completely misleading.

Comment: The people who are still looking for the feature. As I said there is NO FEATURE to disable the link, and hiding the logo, blocking the touch, or any other ways, that's you are against the TOS.

Comment: @wf9a5m75   then how uber and lyft do the same as i can see clicking on goole logo don't open google map in uber

Comment: They have special contract with Google.

Comment: So it's possible. Link to how to sign this special contract plz.